# Efficient groupby() coding for pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have written the following code, and I get what I need. However, I am wondering whether there's an easier/efficient way of achieving the same.

```
job_hist.groupby('employee_id').count()[job_hist.groupby('employee_id').count()['start_date'] > 1]
```

See that I have repeated `job_hist.groupby('employee_id').count()` inside [ ] after count().

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like it can be optimized, but can you share some sample data first & explain what's the desired output you're looking to achieve?

Comment: why not: `cnt = job_hist.groupby('employee_id').count()` and then `cnt.loc[cnt['start_date'] > 1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want all the columns (e.g. because some of them may contain `NaN`), then:

```py
cnt = job_hist.groupby('employee_id').count()
out = cnt.loc[cnt['start_date'] > 1]
```

But a more customary goal is simply to count how many rows there are for each `employee_id`:

```py
cnt = job_hist.groupby('employee_id').size()
out = cnt.loc[cnt > 1]
```

Or, in one go:

```py
out = job_hist.groupby('employee_id').size().to_frame('cnt').query('cnt > 1')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The last one is the one I was looking for.